# I want to shift discount money with percentage below the price that showing in bottom in Woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

The following code shows discount money with a percentage as shown in the picture.
[image]
https://neobery.com/product/motorcycle-repair-shop-dark-teal-printed-tshirt/

This is my code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'simple_product_saving_amount', 11 );
function simple_product_saving_amount() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $regular_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
        $active_price  = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );

        $saved_amount  = $regular_price - $active_price;
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $regular_price * 100 );

        echo '<p id="saving_total_price">'. __("You Save") .': ' . wc_price($saved_amount) . ' ('.$percentage.'%)</p>';
    }
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variable_product_saving_amount', 10, 3 );
function variable_product_saving_amount( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
        $saved_amount  = $data['display_regular_price'] - $data['display_price'];
        $percentage    = round( $saved_amount / $data['display_regular_price'] * 100 );

        $data['price_html'] .= '<p id="saving_total_price">'. __("You Save") .': ' . wc_price($saved_amount) . ' ('.$percentage.'%)</p>';

    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: variable_product_saving_amount must be hooked in woocommerce_single_product_summary with priority 12 and update variation with js since variation form does that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, It helped me a lot. but worked only for the variable products, what will be for the sample products